# Redirecting to a diferent exe for download based on user agent

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, scripting, redirect

I own a Linux-Apache site where I host exe files for download.

Now, when a user clicks this link to my site (published on another site):
http://mysite.com/downloads/file.exe
I need to dynamically check their user agent and redirect them to either
http://mysite.com/downloads/file-1.exe
or
http://mysite.com/downloads/file-2.exe

It seems to me that I have two options:

1. Put a .htaccess file stating that .exe files should be considered to be scripts. Then write a script that checks the user agent and redirects to a real exe placed in another folder. Call this script file.exe.
2. Use Apache mod-rewrite to point file.exe to redirect.php.

Which of these is better? Any other considerations? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason the link to the file has to be http://mysite.com/downloads/file.exe?  It would be more straightforward if, instead of conditionally redirecting them at the web server level, your link was to http://mysite.com/downloads/get-file.php (or cgi, or jsp, whatever) instead.  In other words, basically option one, but making the file link directly to the script rather than redirecting.